# How to check if JS object keys have the same value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

This is what I got so far, first I fetch the JSON from firebase, then .map() it and return it as a JSX... And it works just fine, but here is the thing...

EDIT: When fetched from firebase it becomes a JS object.

Every JS object has a key time, how can I conditionally check if a key time from one JS object is the same as from the other JS object?

I basically want to output only JS objects's that have the same time key to JSX, than other JS objects's with the same key but different value than the first to the other JSX... If that makes any sense...

Thanks

[image]

```
axios
      .get(`...firebaseio.com/users/${uid}/orders.json`)
      .then(response => {
        const fetchedOrders = [];
        for (let key in response.data) {
          fetchedOrders.push({
            ...response.data[key],
            id: key
          });
        }
        this.setState({ orders: fetchedOrders });
      });
```

sdsd

```
    this.state.orders.map(order => {
                  return (
                    <TouchableOpacity
                      key={order.id}
                      onPress={() => this.deleteSingleItemHandler(order.id)}
                    >
                          <View>
                             <Text>{order.articleName}</Text>
                          </View>

                          <View >
                            <Text>{order.articlePrice}</Text>
                          </View>

                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  );
                })
```

Comment: Can you provide structure or example of your data JSON?

Comment: @KarlenKishmiryan Hi, I just edited the question.

Comment: The JSX is really irrelevant here. You want to map the data response first but it's really not clear what you are asking to accomplish with that data

Comment: @charlietfl ,every JSON is a single food item on order ticket... For now i output in JSX every single food item separately and I want to based on key time, output it in one order ticket.

Comment: So your issue is how to group array data based on a common property value. Start by simplifying this down to just some data input and expected results for that data. Then worry about the JSX display later

Comment: @Philip I edited the question and added the structure.

Comment: @charlietfl  Not sure exactly what you mean, can you elaborate ?

Comment: You want to group the items with same time ...correct? So forget the display for now and simplify this down to grouping array data first. Then when that is sorted out work on display of that grouped data

Comment: JSON has NO keys. JSON is a string that needs to be parsed into a JavaScript Object.  Please either provide the actual string OR the parsed object in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss sorry, my bad, it is actually a js object when fetched from firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Just take the values out of your `orders` object and sort them by time before rendering them. Here's the working example:

```js
const fetchedOrders = {"a":{"time":"2018-11-08T11:52:22.668Z"},"b":{"time":"2018-11-08T11:52:28.746Z"},"c":{"time":"2018-11-08T11:52:44.964Z"},"d":{"time":"2018-11-08T11:52:44.964Z"},"e":{"time":"2018-11-08T11:52:52.825Z"},"f":{"time":"2018-11-08T11:52:52.825Z"}};

const orders = Object.values(fetchedOrders)
  .sort((order1, order2) => order1.time - order2.time);
  
// just for showing the result in dom
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(orders, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: @charlietfl in my example I used some strings as dates just to make it clear. If they are `Date` objects, then my comparison is right. I don't suppose to use `localeCompare` with dates.